# Access local files from directory outside SmartGWT deployment?

Tags: java, image, user-interface, smartgwt

I have a problem. I'm creating an app with SmartGWT that just I am going to use. I currently have a directory with thousands of directories corresponding to a user name and then each directory has numerous images. This is on the root of my D drive.

How can I get SmartGWT to access this? I've tried something like the TileGrid example on the showcase, but it doesn't let me specify an absolute location. Is this even possible?

I'd like to avoid having to write some kind of service to access these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartGWT is not meant to create local applications, not to mention that browsers will balk at accessing directory lists of local files. the best you can hope is to create a symlink to the folder, placed in a location within the app directory. And don't even think about enumerating files from within javascript.

Comment: I have the file names from a service, was just hoping I could save me some effort by directly looking at the absolute location. I'll just figure out another way to store or access my files, then. Thanks.

Comment: The simlink worked for me. This is just a personal project so at that point, without seeing an easier way, I'm going with this.